# How to get the pointer to a NSPanel object within a Nib file when the Nib file is loaded by [NSBundle loadNibName: owner:]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

Am working on a tutorial exercise on Cocoa in which a nib file containing a NSPanel object is to be loaded with the [NSBundle loadNibName: owner:] method.  The nib file got loaded ok and the NSPanel object is displayed.  But I need to get the NSPanel object pointer value so that I can assign it to a pointer variable.  Wish that someone more knowledgable than me can give me some suggestions on how to do this ...

Comment: Typing error : "loadNibName" should be "loadNibNamed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what IBOutlets are for. In your class, add an instance variable "IBOutlet NSPanel *panel;" In the Interface Builder editor, set the File's Owner for your Interface Builder document to have a custom class that matches your class, and then connect the File's Owner's "panel" outlet to your panel.

When you invoke -[NSBundle loadNibName:owner:], pass your object in as  the owner.

Many developers have a difficult time grasping the File's Owner. It's a placeholder object for the object that will do the NIB loading. Actions, outlets, and bindings connected to it will resolve against the object passed in through the owner: parameter of -[NSBundle loadNibName:owner:].